# Difference between global and local environment variables in Linux? Usage and Example

Tags: linux, environment-variables, global

Path is an environment variable but i don't know whether its' a global or local environment variable. I need example for global and local environment variables and their usage in reference to Linux. 
Its a question from my paper and i didn't study global or local environment variables. However, I have gone through shell and environment variables. So, i guess one of them (shell and environment) is global and local.

Comment: What do you mean by global and local variables? There's just a set of environment variables that a process sees.

Answer (score 1):

Because you specifically referenced the `PATH` variable, I'm going to assume you're referring to variables that impact a user in terminal mode on Linux. Even so, these two terms can have various meanings.

An example:
Most linux distros will have a file called `/etc/bashrc` (or `/etc/bash_profile`, etc. depending on distro). This file will contain settings variables for the bash shell as determined by the system administrator. These are "global" or "environment" variables, and it includes the `PATH` variable, but it also sets things like whether or not some commands provide their output in color, what the shell prompt looks like, etc.

Some power-users will not be satisfied with these defaults, and want to change them. They can create a file called `/home/poweruser/.bashrc`, and inside they can override most if not all of the variables in `/etc/bashrc`. Another example of this would be creating a custom `~/.vimrc`, or even setting variables temporarily on the command line like so:

```
$ LANG=utf8
$ echo $LANG
utf8
```

This link has more information on the differences between the two and how to look at what variables are set on your shell: http://howtolamp.com/articles/difference-between-local-and-environment-variables/